# Reason why kernel density graphs are so different in Python versus R

Tags: r, python, kernel-smoothing

I plotted the same data in R using `geom_density`, but the blip for "Yes" is much, much smaller in Python using `kdeplot` from Seaborn than for R.

I am using the dataset `default` from the `ISLR` package. It's included for R and I downloaded it for Python from this [link](https://github.com/jasonm/islr-exercises).

R code:

```
install.packages("ISLR")
install.packages("tibble")
install.packages("ggplot2")

library("ISLR")
library("tibble")
library("ggplot2")
df <- as_tibble(Default)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=balance, color=default)) + 
  geom_density()
```

Output:

[image]

Python code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

default = pd.read_excel(r"")

sns.kdeplot(data=default, hue='default', x="balance")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

I'm following this [tutorial](https://rpubs.com/aelhabr/logistic-regression-tutorial) on logistic regression.

Can anyone explain to me in detail how the implementation in `kdeplot` versus `geom_density` results in these different graphs? I read the docs ([kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html), [geom_density](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html)) but I'm can't see a clear reason.

I really want to understand as I use Python for my work as a data analyst, want to learn forecasting techniques for my job, and would like to also learn R. I don't have much statistics background but I have calculus background, if that's relevant to understanding the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the R version, the two curves are kernel density estimates for the densities in the two groups. The area under each curve is 1.

According to the documentation you linked, `kdeplot` has an option

> `common_norm` `bool`
> If `True`, scale each conditional density by the number of observations such that the total area under all densities sums to 1. Otherwise, normalize each density independently.

The default is `True`, so that's what you got.  This means that the two curves are **rescaled** density estimates in the two groups. Rather than the area under each curve being 1, as it is for a density, the area has been scaled to be proportional to the number of observations in the group. The numbers are

```
> table(Default$default)

  No  Yes 
9667  333
```

So in the Python version the `Yes` curve is scaled to about 3.4% of the height of the `No` curve, but you can fix this with the `common_norm` option.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!